# Jenkins job to update ios project

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

Are there any jenkins plugin available that helps updating an ios project for example change app icon, splash screen before generating a build? I want to create a jenkins job that is able to perform aforementioned tasks before generating a build.

Thanks

Comment: You could potentially use Fastlane, which will work with Jenkins but is independent. We use it to update our app icon before submitting to Hockey.

Comment: We use shell scripts as pre-build step in Jenkins.

Comment: @shallowThought,can you please point me to the scripts that performs actions like appicon, splash screen update?

Comment: Slightly off topic but also nice approach: https://engineering.circle.com/different-app-icons-for-your-ios-beta-dev-and-release-builds-af4d209cdbfd